# How to create unit and quantity "amount per area unit" in JSR-363?

Tags: java, units, measurements

I am trying to integrate units and quantity with JSR-363.
I know and understand how to create  SI and NONSI units and convert e.g. Areas units  from one to another.

But, in a kind of geographic cartographic way, I want to create another unit: from absolute population number to a relative on e.g. population per km²

First question: In what unit can I put numbers with plane quantities numbers
like population number or amount of eggs.

Second question:
How can I create a new unit with combination with Area and amount number
without any java.lang.ClassCastException

I am using maven packages and Java 8

```
</dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.measure</groupId>
      <artifactId>unit-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>tec.units</groupId>
      <artifactId>unit-ri</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.3</version>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>si.uom</groupId>
  <artifactId>si-units-java8</artifactId>
  <version>0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

and the example

```
 Quantity<Area> area = Quantities.getQuantity(4000.0,SI.SQUARE_METRE);
 Quantity<*????*> population = Quantities.getQuantity(60, *????*);

 Quantity< ???> result= population.divide(area).getValue();
```

The goal is to use any number for population and any number of area, where it is also possible to switch between m² or km² or any other area unit

What I also don't really understand is, how to get units and values from a calculation in a new Quantity class ala result?

==== UPDATE

with the code example and BaseUnit I can create the result.

but with my maven packages I get an Exception

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Unit
at tec.units.ri.format.SimpleUnitFormat$DefaultFormat.format(SimpleUnitFormat.java:692)
at tec.units.ri.format.QuantityFormat$Standard.format(QuantityFormat.java:188)
at tec.units.ri.format.QuantityFormat.format(QuantityFormat.java:125)
at tec.units.ri.format.QuantityFormat.format(QuantityFormat.java:143)
at tec.units.ri.quantity.DoubleQuantity.toString(DoubleQuantity.java:121)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821)
```

it is working, if I use the getValue or getUnit method.
But this way is less

```
import si.uom.SI;
import tec.units.ri.quantity.Quantities;
import tec.units.ri.unit.BaseUnit;

import javax.measure.Quantity;
import javax.measure.quantity.Area;
import javax.measure.quantity.Dimensionless;

public class App{
    public static void main( String[] args ){

    BaseUnit<Dimensionless> PEOPLE = new BaseUnit<>("people");

    Quantity<Area> area = Quantities.getQuantity(4000.0, SI.SQUARE_METRE);

    Quantity<Dimensionless> pop = Quantities.getQuantity(1000, PEOPLE);

    System.out.println(area); //not working with exception
    System.out.println(pop); //not working with exception
    System.out.println(pop.divide(area));//not working with exception


    System.out.println(pop.divide(area).getValue());
    System.out.println(pop.divide(area).getUnit());




  }
}
```

Comment: I seem to be using slightly different imports to you, see my update

Answer (score 1):

From a quick test it seems like you can create a new `BaseUnit` people and use it as you'd expect.

```
import si.uom.NonSI;
import si.uom.SI;
import systems.uom.common.USCustomary;
import tec.uom.se.quantity.Quantities;
import tec.uom.se.unit.BaseUnit;
import tec.uom.se.unit.MetricPrefix;
```

...

```
BaseUnit<Dimensionless> PEOPLE = new BaseUnit<>("people");
javax.measure.Quantity<Dimensionless> pop = Quantities.getQuantity(10000, PEOPLE);

javax.measure.Quantity<Area> a = me.calcArea(feature);
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(pop);
System.out.println(pop.divide(a));
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Unit<Area> sq_km = (Unit<Area>) MetricPrefix.KILO(SI.METRE).multiply(MetricPrefix.KILO(SI.METRE));
System.out.println(a.to(sq_km));
System.out.println(pop.divide(a.to(sq_km)));
```

gives me the expected:

```
469013.24064056645 m²
10000 people
0.02132135968345425028597612117922469 people/m²
0.46901324064056643 km²
21321.35968345425119517687868168138 people/km²
0.1810870245963103 mi²
46.901324064056645 ha
115.89569574163858 acres
```

I'm using [GeoTools](https://geotools.org) as my base so I'm depending on

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>systems.uom</groupId>
  <artifactId>systems-common-java8</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

which pulls in `uom-se` 1.0.8.

Comment: ah thanks. Quantity<Dimensionless> was the mising info for me. unfortunatelly i get an exceptions during print  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Unit